# PHP Displaying number of clicks of a link

Tags: php, html, function, variables, hyperlink

i want to count the number of the clicks of a link and post the click count . i use the following code but it displays count as 0 . i can't figure the mistake where it is . however i can guess that the "Clicks" is not implemented properly in  .. kindly help me please.

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("clickcount.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $count = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("clickcount.txt", $count);
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Click Count</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" name="clicks">Google</a>
</ br>
</ br>
<div>Click Count: <?php echo getClickCount(); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If possible, it would probably be a lot better to do this with a database.

Comment: @samankhademi i can't understand what u r trying to say ???

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 i accept your suggestion and by the way can you figure out the error here ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not posting with the click variable, so it will never run.
Have you considered using Google analytics or some other analytics sollution?

What you are making here, is most valuable as a hit counter. Though it's very easy to manipulate it, as you cant filter out repeated hits by user, or search engines in a simple way.

If you want to make a script that logs hits to external links, you need some sort of "banner exchange" logging. I would make this with databases, so you can records hits per outgoing link. Such a sollution I would make with an "out"-script (as you see facebook and others have).

If you still wish to make this "log" function / hit counter, you will need to trigger it properly. Either change how it triggers, or post the variables upon the hyperlink (or change to form). You can trick the post via JQuery or Vanilla JS, yet a form would be more robust.

Comment: Now my question turns , if i use google url shortner goo.gl
How to echo back click counts to a part of my site  which is displayed in goo.gl

Comment: If you are generating hits from your webpage, you can make an out-script. THis out-script will work like goo.gl , where there is a parameter for the target. It's not very hard to make.

You need to make the target link shortener code. The MD5 hash might be a bit long, so maybe you just make a long order of hashes that are unique and tie them to shorteners/targets.

Then on your "out" page, you simply select the URL from your DB. You also increment a value on the "out". Then there are a very few lines of PHP, with location 301 (permanently moved).

You can also trigger Google Analytics :)